# Python selenium scrape pages that refresh with javascript, unable to get elements from the new javascript page

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Hello i'd like to **scrape** a webpage

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpD2C.png)
as you can see, when you go on page 2, the url dosnt change and when i try to find an element from here, it dosnt work and display this error: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:

When i try to select it in page 1, this works but not on page 2 with :

```
restaurant = driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//div[@class='OhCyu'])[" + numberxd +"]")
```

same code on page2 dosnt work

Would really appreciate your help,
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use xpath, CSS_Selector might be a better method. Without seeing the HTML, it's hard to see the issue. Maybe the page isn't fully loaded, did you tried to put a `time.sleep(10)`?

You can find every CSS selector [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

With a CSS Selector, it should look like this, but without seeing this part of the HTML, I can't be more precise.

```
restaurant = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div[@class="OhCyu"]')
```